# split flac track with ffmpeg

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I'm trying to split a flac soundtrack into several files but it fails with `Output file #0 does not contain any stream`. The file is actually a flac encoded in an ogg container, but I have the same problem with regular flac files.

The command:
`ffmpeg.exe -i D:\_\RecManagerTests\103_1.flog -f segment -segment_time 30 -c copy D:\_\RecManagerTests\StreamingChunks/103_1_%03d.flog`

The output:

```
ffmpeg version N-100131-g0639f5c294 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg
developers   built with gcc 9.3-win32 (GCC) 20200320   configuration:
--prefix=/ffbuild/prefix --pkg-config-flags=--static --pkg-config=pkg-config --cross-prefix=x86_64-w64-mingw32- --arch=x86_64 --target-os=mingw32 --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-debug --enable-shared --disable-static --disable-debug --disable-w32threads --enable-pthreads --enable-iconv --enable-zlib --enable-libxml2 --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-gmp --enable-lzma --enable-fontconfig --enable-opencl --enable-libvmaf --enable-vulkan --enable-libvorbis --enable-amf --enable-libaom --enable-avisynth --enable-libdav1d --enable-libdavs2 --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-libglslang --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libmfx --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librav1e --enable-librubberband --enable-schannel --enable-sdl2 --enable-libsoxr --enable-libsrt --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libtwolame --enable-libuavs3d --enable-libvidstab --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --extra-cflags=-DLIBTWOLAME_STATIC --extra-cxxflags= --extra-ldflags=-pthread --extra-libs=-lgomp   libavutil      56. 61.100 / 56. 61.100   libavcodec     58.114.100 / 58.114.100   libavformat    58. 64.100 / 58. 64.100   libavdevice    58. 11.103 /
58. 11.103   libavfilter     7. 91.100 /  7. 91.100   libswscale      5.  8.100 /  5.  8.100   libswresample   3.  8.100 /  3.  8.100   libpostproc    55.  8.100 / 55.  8.100 **Input #0**, ogg, from
'D:\_\RecManagerTests\103_1.flog':   Duration: 00:07:14.68, start:
0.000000, bitrate: 467 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: flac, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.114.100 flac Output #0, segment, to 'D:\_\RecManagerTests\StreamingChunks/103_1_%03d.flog': **Output file #0
does not contain any stream**
```

Comment: FFmpeg recognizes the file format by the file extension, and with `segment` muxer, extension rules of the output files are more restrict . Try replacing `103_1_%03d.flog` with `103_1_%03d.ogg` or with `103_1_%03d.flac`. Try updating FFmpeg - it looks like you are not using an official stable release (unless it's on purpose).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @Rotem, the target extension is determining the target format/encoding, `flog` is a made up extension (flac + ogg), and using instead for instance `flac` was solving the issue:

```
ffmpeg.exe -i source.flog -f segment -segment_time 30 -c copy target_%03d.flac
```